# Temporary Beam support help please

Tags: beam, support

I am enlarging and moving a cased opening in a basement wall.  The wall is 2x6.  Current size of opening is 3' wide and I am enlarging it to  4 to 5' wide.  There are open web floor trusses 16" OC supporting the floor above and the attic and roof above that.   I know I need to temporarily support the trusses on each side of the wall as well as the beam but am wondering if I used 2  4x4 adjustable shoring  jacks with the 4x4's supporting a pair of 2x6x8's on edge and screwed together and had one of those setups on each side of the wall being modified if that would be sufficient support or even overkill.  And could I use a 4x4 post jack under the end of the beam?  I am attaching notated pictures of the attic and base[image]ment.
Thanks for your feedback and assistance

as requested the beam in the basement has one living space above then the attic and roof above.  I hope this is enough information

---

here is picture 1 of the basement beam and trusses[image]

---

Here is picture 2 of the basement beam and trusses[image]

Comment: You need to find the end reaction of the truss, and the number of  trusses need to be supported during the widening, also, their location/position on the proposed temporary support beam, with respect to the beam ends.

Comment: Questions like this aren't answerable without knowing what the _floor_ is holding up. Is there a primary bearing wall or a stone fireplace directly above? How many stories are we talking about? Context matters. You can't just ask whether two 2x6s will carry a house. We have no idea.

Comment: Are the existing open web trusses top chord bearing or bottom chord bearing and how far do they span on each side of the wall?

Comment: Here is the first basement picture

Comment: Great pictures, thanks, but still need area contributing load to wall...again, how far do the trusses span on each side of the wall?

Comment: There is a one story living area with an attic and roof above the basement where the basement where the beam is located.  The beam runs parallel to a 2x4 wall above.  There is nothing remarkable above the wall in the attic  Above th

Comment: The trusses total span are 28' and terminate on the 2x6 wall that is next to the 2x4 wall.  So, starting at the outside wall it's 14' to the first load bearing wall ,where point B of the beam also rest, then goes another 14' terminating on the 2x6 wall where point A of the beam is.  The next truss starts there and travels 18' to the next load bearing wall and then another 12' to the other outside wall.  In terms of top bearing or bottom bearing I assume they are bottom since there is 3/4 subfloor above and there are either vertical members or  V where the truss rest on the walls in question